# 100 Mb/s port limit reached or something else?

Tags: performance, port, bandwidth

I have a dedicated server with a 100 Mbps port. A few times a week, there comes a time (usually in the evening hours) when there is an extremely high bandwidth usage, by far more than usual.

I am on CentOS 6 with cPanel and host a few dozen websites. I have installed **IPTraf** to be able to monitor the bandwidth usage in real time. During those evening hours, the **lo** interface shows about 55 - 90 Mb/s and the **eth0** interface about 5 to 20 Mb/s. Which, added together, equals about 70 to 100 Mb/s. This lasts for about 3-4 hours and the server is hardly reachable. After that, the activity drops to something between 100 Kb/s and 2 Mb/s and it stays that way for the majority of hours during the day.

I also have **csf** installed and I have only allowed certain ports to go through, but in IPTraf's traffic monitor I see a lot of IP addresses with random ports like 51970 or 45398 connecting to the server.

What issue could I be facing here?

Comment: Do you have some kind of backup scheduled to happen at that point in time?

Comment: No, backups are around 4-5 AM. All I know is that there is an increased demand for a few websites in the evening.

Comment: Also you might want to use `sar` to monitor io/cpu during the night as well

Comment: So much traffic through `lo` is strange... `eth0` is physical, `lo` is internal (doesn't use up bandwith), so it isn't network. The "random ports" from which the connections come are normal, BTW.

Comment: There's currently a peak on the server again and my `lo` interface shows around 140 Mb/s and even more (and `eth0` is about 30 Mb/s). What could that mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most part, you can ignore `lo` traffic. That is your loopback adapter, which is used by various linux subsystems. That adapter exists purely within the linux kernel, and traffic through it *does not* touch your `eth0` interface.

The connections you're seeing from high ports are expected. Those are the ports the **client** opens to make connections to the services you have running on the server.

The easiest way to determine the nature of the traffic spike is likely to watch your webserver access logs.

Beyond webserver logs, to further diagnose the nature of the traffic, you'll need to perform a packet capture. Install `tcpdump` and then do something like:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -w packet.cap
```

This will start a packet capture, writing capture packets to `packet.cap`. Kill that process when you think you've captured enough traffic, download `packet.cap`, install Wireshark on your local system, and use that to open up the packet capture file.